# How to wait for promise to finish before function returns

Tags: javascript, promise

Basic promise question:

```js
console.log('Promise START');

function makeFullJSON(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time, [time]);
  })
}

var p1 = makeFullJSON(1000);
var p2 = makeFullJSON(500);
var p3 = makeFullJSON(750);

p1.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 1 complete', array);
});

p2.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 2 complete', array);
});

p3.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 3 complete', array);
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(arrayOfAllResolvedValues => {
  console.log('Array of resolved values:', arrayOfAllResolvedValues);
});

console.log('Promise END');
```

The code output is:

```
Promise START
Promise END
Promise 2 complete [ 500 ]
Promise 3 complete [ 750 ]
Promise 1 complete [ 1000 ]
Array of resolved values: [ [ 1000 ], [ 500 ], [ 750 ] ]
```

How do you rewrite the code, such that output is:

```
Promise START
Promise 2 complete [ 500 ]
Promise 3 complete [ 750 ]
Promise 1 complete [ 1000 ]
Array of resolved values: [ [ 1000 ], [ 500 ], [ 750 ] ]
Promise END
```

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/497418.

Comment: Just put the *Promise END* `console.log` next to the *resolved values* one?

Comment: `Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(() => console.log('Promise END'))`

Comment: You can't ever cause the interpreter in Javascript to "wait" for any async operation.  Instead, you do what you always do in any single-threaded, event-driven system - you register a callback to get notified when the operation is done and you carry out your work in that callback.  You don't "wait" in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks all. I agree with the callback notification. That seems to be the only way for now (until i get to use async await pattern).

Answer (score 7):

Anything that you want to happen after the completion goes in the arrow function that you pass to then.

```
    console.log('Promise START')
    
    function makeFullJSON(time) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(resolve, time, [time])
    })}
    
    var p1 = makeFullJSON(1000)
    var p2 = makeFullJSON(500)
    var p3 = makeFullJSON(750)
    
    p1.then(array => {
        console.log('Promise 1 complete', array)})
    
    p2.then(array => {
        console.log('Promise 2 complete', array)})
    
    p3.then(array => {
        console.log('Promise 3 complete', array)})
    
    Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(arrayOfAllResolvedValues => {
        console.log('Array of resolved values:', arrayOfAllResolvedValues)
    
        console.log('Promise END')
    })
```

In order to abandon immediate program execution, and start writing code which would happen only after all 3 promises resolve, as it sounds like you want to happen, then I would recommend creating a new function directly below your code, to contain code which you would like to happen after resolution, and pass that function like: `Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(newFunctionName)`. It might be easier for you to visualize it that way, at least until you get used to thinking about how it works precisely.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer explains everything. Thanks Kent. You saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

First fix the syntax error. Then move the console.log to where the entire process ends:

```js
console.log('Promise START');

function makeFullJSON(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time, [time]);
  })}

var p1 = makeFullJSON(1000);
var p2 = makeFullJSON(500);
var p3 = makeFullJSON(750);

p1.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 1 complete', array);});

p2.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 2 complete', array);});  // fixed syntax error here

p3.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 3 complete', array);});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(arrayOfAllResolvedValues => {
  console.log('Array of resolved values:', arrayOfAllResolvedValues);
  console.log('Promise END');
});
```

Comment: `console.log('Promise 2 complete', array););`

Comment: Ah, hadn't spotted that. It's always good to point such things out with a comment in the respective position

Comment: Good advice. Done

Answer (score 1):

If the obvious answer of placing the `console.log('Promise END')` doesnt float your boat, why not this?

```
//didnt change anything at all above here
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(arrayOfAllResolvedValues => {
    console.log('Array of resolved values:', arrayOfAllResolvedValues);
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Promise END');
});
```

If you want to sequence an operation after all promises were fulfilled, you have to sequence with `then()` just as you are doing when you print your array values

Answer (score 0):

Use `async`/`await`:

```js
(async () => {
  console.log('Promise START');

  function makeFullJSON(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time, [time]); 
  })}

  var p1 = makeFullJSON(1000);
  var p2 = makeFullJSON(500);
  var p3 = makeFullJSON(750);

  p1.then(array => {
    console.log('Promise 1 complete', array);});

  p2.then(array => {
    console.log('Promise 2 complete', array);});

  p3.then(array => {
    console.log('Promise 3 complete', array);});

  console.log('Array of resolved values:', await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]));

  console.log('Promise END');
})();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your comments. The issue is that, what if the above code is in  function A that is called by another function B. Function B needs all the promises to finish after calling A, for it to continue. This is similar to await pattern. The only way I know to solve this problem (without await) is to pass a callback to function A and called it in Promise.all (as was suggested). A am I correct?

Comment: @S.Vaghar Have function A return the promise from `Promise.all`?